# ¿Cómo convierto un un array de String en un arbol binario? JAVA

Tags: java, lista, árboles-binarios

Almacené un árbol binario en una cadena (utilizando un recorrido preorden) para guardarlo en un archivo de tal manera que la información cada nodo tiene un indicativo al inicio (en este caso un $ para nodo padre, un #para nodo hijo izquierdo y un % para cada hijo derecho). Cabe aclarar que cada nodo que no tenga el indicativo $, será unahoja. EL problema está cuando necesito recuperar esa información nuevamente y armar el árbol a partir de un nodo raíz.

Necesito una función que me reciba un vector de String y me devuelva el nodo raíz. Intenté esto, pero no funciona:

```
     public static Node receiveFromFile(String[] tmp, int i) {
    Node $root = new Node();
    Node izq = new Node();
    Node der = new Node();
    if (tmp.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Archivo vacío");
    } else {

        if (tmp[i].substring(0, 0) == "$" && tmp[i + 1].substring(0, 0) == "#" && tmp[i].substring(0, 0) == "%") {
            $root.setData(tmp[i].substring(1, tmp[i].length()));
            i++;
            izq.setData(tmp[i].substring(1, tmp[i + 1].length()));
            $root.setIzq(izq);
            i++;
            der.setData(tmp[i].substring(1, tmp[i + 2].length()));
            $root.setDer(der);
            return $root;
        } else {

            $root.setData(tmp[i].substring(1, tmp[i].length()));
            i++;
            izq = receiveFromFile(tmp,i);
            $root.setIzq(izq);
            i++;
            der = receiveFromFile(tmp,i);
            $root.setIzq(izq);

        }

    }
    return $root;
}
```